# Recaptcha Client Validation

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha, client-side-validation

Is there any way to restrict user on client side to must fill recaptcha before going to server sdie ?

I know we can check on server side by putting `!Page.IsValid` but I want client validation before submitting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have never used ASP.Net.

You cannot prevent someone from submitting a form.

However, in most cases, it is possible to block the submission of a form by using some Javascript.

To do this, try to validate the of the form element that reCAPTCHA generates using Javascript/jQuery. The simplest method would be to check if the entered value's string-length is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.. by disabling the button itself.. did the same thing a while back.

this is my recaptcha

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="EnableButton" data-expired-callback="DisableButton" data-sitekey="your-site-key"></div>
```

and these are the javascript functions i used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var DisableButton = function () {
        alert("Confirmation Expired. Please Answer Recaptcha.");
        document.getElementById('buttonID').disabled = true;
        grecaptcha.reset();
    };
    var EnableButton = function () {
        document.getElementById('buttonID').disabled = false;
    };

</script>
```

p.s. i used google recaptcha 2.0

its incredibly easy to use. and its FREE.